# ionic+vueでアプリを作成していてcapacitorを使っているがandroid studioでビルドが通らない

Tags: android-studio, vue.js, ionic2

現在ionic + vue.jsでアプリを開発しています。
capacitorを使用してandroidとiosに変換してエミュレーターで動作確認しています。
iosでのエミュレータは動いているのですが
androidのエミュレーターではビルドがうまくいっていません。

エラー文は以下の通りです

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/kazumasa/3StepWallet-Core/android/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/resources/AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.sample.3StepWallet.Vue'.
```

試したこととしては、

```
$ npx cap init [appName] [appId]

$ mv dist www
$ npx cap add ios
$ npx cap add android
$ npx cap sync
```

そして

```
$ npx cap open ios
```

だとうまくいきました
ここで本題なのですが

```
$ npx cap open android
```

だとエラー文が出ました。

お答えいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

パッケージ名が"com.sample.**3StepWallet**.Vue"のように、数字で始まっているのが原因ではないでしょうか。数字やアンダーバーが使えるのは**二文字目以降**のようです。

参考：

- [What is the rule of the name of the packages that start with number? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12041857/2322778)
- [Androidのパッケージ名に使える文字 - しるてく](http://ofsilvers.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/01/12/142323)

> 基本は英字。 **先頭でなければ** 数字と`_`が使える。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法でうまくビルドが通りました！！